# не работает команда discord.py после time.sleep

Tags: python, discord.py

я собирался сделать так чтобы при отправке команды !таймер (время) бот отвечал другим сообщением спустя время указанное в аргументе команды, для этого я использовал time.sleep(args) но после time.sleep дальнейший код не выполняется.
вот код команды:

```
@bot.command()
async def таймер(ctx, *,args):
    await ctx.send("ожидайте")
    time.sleep(args)
    await ctx.send("спасибо")
```

ошибка выдающаяся в консоли:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

сообщение "ожидайте" отправляется. дальше ошибка в консоли и бот молчит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По дефолту discord строка str, поэтому вам надо преобразовать args в int

```
int(args)
```

ну или заранее об этом объявить

```
async def таймер(ctx, *, args: int):
```